# Check if a week is between two weeks

Tags: javascript

I want to return true if a week is between two weeks. I.e., the period is week 48 (2021) to week 3 (2022). I then want to return true if a week is in between.

Lesson week and year is what I'm checking is inbetween. Start week & year and end week & year is the period.

My code below doesn't work for the example (week 48 2021 -> week 3 2022)

I'd rather not convert to Date objects but if it's needed I will.

```
const isSamePeriod = (
  lessonWeek,
  lessonYear,
  startWeek,
  startYear,
  endWeek,
  endYear
) => {
  if (lessonWeek >= startWeek && lessonYear === startYear) {
    if (lessonWeek <= endWeek && lessonYear === endYear) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Did you try using moment.js (luxon)?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the values as strings of year + week provided the week is zero padded, then compare, e.g.

```js
const isSamePeriod = (
  lessonWeek,
  lessonYear,
  startWeek,
  startYear,
  endWeek,
  endYear
) => {
  let z = n => ('0'+n).slice(-2);
  let lesson = lessonYear + z(lessonWeek);
  let start =  startYear + z(startWeek);
  let end =  endYear + z(endWeek);
  return lesson >= start && lesson <= end;
};

// Examples
[[47,2021],
 [48,2021],
 [50,2021],
 [ 1,2022],
 [ 3,2022],
 [ 4,2022]
].forEach(
   arr => console.log(arr + ' ' + isSamePeriod(...arr, 48,2021, 3,2022))
 );
```

You can also convert the week, year values to Dates, e.g.

```js
// Convert year, week to Date
// Assumes ISO week: week starts on Monday, first week
// starts on Monday before first Thursday of year
function yearWeekToDate(year, week) {
  // 4th is always in first week
  let d = new Date(year, 0, 4);
  // Shift to prior Monday if not Monday
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay() + 1);
  // Add 7 days for each week, decrement week number
  // as index starts at 1
  // This could be included in the above adjustment
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7 * (week - 1))
  return d;
}

const isSamePeriod = (
  lessonWeek,
  lessonYear,
  startWeek,
  startYear,
  endWeek,
  endYear
) => {
  let lesson = yearWeekToDate(lessonYear, lessonWeek);
  return lesson >= yearWeekToDate(startYear, startWeek) &&
         lesson <= yearWeekToDate(endYear, endWeek)
};

// Examples
[[47,2021],
 [48,2021],
 [50,2021],
 [ 1,2022],
 [ 3,2022],
 [ 4,2022]
].forEach(
  arr => console.log(`${arr} ${isSamePeriod(...arr, 48,2021, 3,2022)}`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The checks need to be separate, but you have the second one nested inside the first. Also, you only need to check the week if the years match; see comments:

```
const isSamePeriod = (
    lessonWeek,
    lessonYear,
    startWeek,
    startYear,
    endWeek,
    endYear
) => {
    return (
        // Year is valid
        (lessonYear >= startYear && lessonYear <= endYear) ||
        // Lesson is not in the start year or is late enough in the start year
        (lessonYear !== startYear || lessonWeek >= startWeek) ||
        // Lesson is not in the end year or is early enough in the end year
        (lessonYear !== endYear || lessonWeek <= endWeek)
    );
};
```

Comment: As some years have 53 weeks, e.g. 2017, the above makes week 53, 2017 (104937) the same value as week 1, 2018 (also 104937). Probably not an issue for the end given the test is `<=` but if it's changed to `==` then it might be. It is an issue for the start, where 53,2017 should be `<` 1, 2018. :-)

Comment: Oh, whether a year has 52 or 53 weeks depends on the definition of when the week count starts. 2017 has 53 weeks if using 1 Jan as the first week. Using ISO weeks (first week is the one with the first Thursday) then 2017 has 52 weeks and 2020 53 weeks.

Comment: @RobG - Good point, I've removed that version. It depends entirely on what the definition of "week" is, and while the OP didn't say, you're almost certainly right that whatever they're using has those complexities.